# PowerShell Form not displaying full Label message

Tags: forms, powershell

hope everyone is safe and doing well during these crazy times we are dealing with. I have a question if you guys can help me. I have a form that I want to display some text next to the button that I created. I am using a label for this and I added a text. The problem is that my text does not show completely in the form. The label with the text is under the comment **INPUT USER INFO LABEL**. Here is the picture of the form as you can see the text cutoff on "butt" which should be "button...":

[image: Form]

As you can see I still have space left in the form but my text is not display completely. I am assuming that a size is involved, some sort of coordinates I have set up is messing with my label and cutting it off. Could you guys lend me a pair of eyes on this matter and let me know why is this happening? Thank you in advance and peace and love fam!!!!!

```
##################################### Form #####################################

# Create new form 
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
# Add title to the window's form
$form.Text = 'Welcome to AD Mortgage Office 365 Testing Environment Version 1.0'
$form.Controls.Add($UserInfoLabel)
$form.Controls.Add($label)
# Add width and height of our window's popup in pixels
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,600)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'



################################# Top Label ########################################

#  Create a label
$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

# Label Styles & Text
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Font =  New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri Light",15)
$label.Text = 'Please select an action:'



################################# CREATE INPUT USER INFO BUTTON #############################

# Store and create a "Create User"  button
$InputUserInfo = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$InputUserInfo.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,80)
$InputUserInfo.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$InputUserInfo.Text = 'Input User Info'
$InputUserInfo.BackColor = "aqua"
$InputUserInfo.Add_Click($function:InputUserInfoButtonClick)

$form.AcceptButton = $InputUserInfo
$form.Controls.Add($InputUserInfo)

################################# INPUT USER INFO LABEL ########################################

#  Create a label
$UserInfoLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

# Label Styles & Text
$UserInfoLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(130,95)
$UserInfoLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$UserInfoLabel.Font =  New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri Light",12)
$UserInfoLabel.Text = 'Please make sure you click the SAVE button on excel!'



################################# CREATE USER BUTTON #############################

# Store and create a "Create User"  button
$CreateButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CreateButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,130)
$CreateButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$CreateButton.Text = 'Create User'
$CreateButton.BackColor = "aqua"

$form.AcceptButton = $CreateButton
$form.Controls.Add($CreateButton)



################################## EDIT BUTTON ###################################

# Store and create  "Edit User"  button
$EditButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
# Style Edit User button
$EditButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,180)
$EditButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$EditButton.Text = 'Edit User'
$EditButton.BackColor = "aqua"

$form.AcceptButton = $EditButton
$form.Controls.Add($EditButton)

################################ BLOCK BUTTON ####################################   

# Store and create  "Block User"  button
$BlockButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
# Style Edit User button
$BlockButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,230)
$BlockButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$BlockButton.Text = 'Block User'
$BlockButton.BackColor = 'aqua'

$form.Topmost = $true
$form.AcceptButton = $BlockButton
$form.Controls.Add($BlockButton)

################################# Bottom Label ########################################


#  Create a label
$BottomLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

# Label Styles & Text
$BottomLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,300)
$BottomLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,50)
$BottomLabel.Font =  New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri Light",15)
$BottomLabel.Text = 'Output message:'
$form.Controls.Add($BottomLabel)

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Seems like the text doesn't fit in the size of your label, have you tried tweaking `$UserInfoLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)` ?

Comment: Wow that was it, thank you so so much. That did it for me. You are awesome. Thank you!!!

Comment: @mklement0 please, feel free to post it as answer, or OP could self-answer. I'm on my phone rn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per **Santiago Squarzon** request this was his answer. Just adding it here since it was the answer to my question.

"Seems like the text doesn't fit in the size of your label, have you tried tweaking."

$UserInfoLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)